# Windows User Switching without interruping code

Tags: windows, operating-system, settings

I am not sure if this is the proper forum for this question. But here goes - I am on Windows 10 and I have 2 users on my laptop - one for each of the research work I am a part of. I am using Selenium + Python to **scrape** some data on one user (say, user_np) and I want to switch users and do some Stata stuff on user_nu. If I switch from user_np to user_nu, what is the possibility that my Selenium + Python code will stop running?

I am afraid to try it out because there is this code that has been running for the past 9 hours and is only halfway through and I do not want to lose the headway upon accidental user switch.

Comment: Try it on another machine, see what happens......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who has the same question, I am answering myself - Due to some internet issues, I lost the 9-hour headway that I had on my program and I could try out the switch method myself. I reran the program from the start, and switched the user to see if it still works - it does. Switching users does not interrupt an already running process. Logging off will.